# Check if JsonResult is true or false on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This code initially calls controller action method:

```
$.post("/Home/IsItemExist", { "itemID": itemID },
function (response) {
    if (response) {
        $('.button.button-main').css('background','#555');
    }
});
```

Following controller action method checks if an item with the given itemID exists or not:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsItemExist(int itemID)
{
    return Json(ItemExists(itemID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public bool ItemExists(int itemID)
{
    return db.Carts.Any(x => x.ItemID == itemID);
}
```

I'm not sure how to check if ajax call returned value is true or false. Right now I'm getting an error on 'response'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?  Can you post that stack trace?

Comment: message: "response is not defined"
stack: "ReferenceError: response is not defined↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> 
__proto__: Error

Comment: It might be "response.data". Use a debugging technique to find out, either: i) put a breakpoint in; ii) put the line "debugger;" as the first line of code in the response function and have Developer Tools open; iii) add console.log(response); then have a look at the console area in Developer Tools. Then you'll be able to see what's happening - what type the response variable is

Comment: Maybe you could also try using a promise-approach to handling the result - `...{ "itemID": itemID }).then(function(result) { var codeHere = true; });` or `...).done(function(result) { ... });`

Comment: `function (response)` is a callback function .. correct?

Comment: Have you tried including the 4th parameter for format?

Comment: When json is returned from controller to view, how to read it

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - all I need is to read if returned json value is true or false .. how can we do that?

Comment: Are you sure the request is actually going through to the controller?  The syntax looks correct so maybe there is something wrong with how the controller is wired.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - controller code is running perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - `if (response)` is checking if ajax success is returned or not. WhileI know its returned, I need to check if it contains a true or a false value. It is a simple question. I wonder why no one has answered it.

Comment: What do you see if you print out the contents of the `response` value?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - `VM3453:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - that error message is what I get when i type `console.log(response);` in console.

Comment: Where are you running the `console.log`?  Right before the `if(response)` line?  Because if `response` is `undefined` like you said it is, that means the variable isn't be populated by the callback function.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt yes right before the `if(response)`.

Comment: What language are you using for your controller?  Maybe the `Json()` method is formatting the data weird?  I can't think of anything else without debugging and stepping through the code.  It sincerely sounds like `response` just isn't being populated.  What about putting a break point where you are building your JSON response and see how that looks in the controller?

Comment: all i need is to see if a record exists in the table or not .. there has to be millions of possible ways to do that .. why can't i define a string in the controller action method and set it to true if item exists in the table and then change it to false it it doesn't and somehow pass that freaking string to view .. and parse it ????

Answer (score 1):

```
function (response) {
            if (response == "true") {
                $('.button.button-main').css('background','#555');
            }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing some more context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: if (response == "true") is equal to  if (response), isnt it ?

Comment: @satsvelke Its json value. Its not boolen.